# Angular 6 Build Components Into Seperate Javascript Files

Tags: webpack, angular6

I am going to develop a very large application using Angular 6 Framework. Angular-6 CLI builds everything into 'main.js' file. However, when I have a lot of components, this script size becomes very large. In addition, I do not want to load components that my user probably will not use. I want to receive the needed component or module from my server separately.

I really could not find a solution, or a good approach for this. I do not know how large projects deal with such problem with Angular. I have tried to modify webpack config, however Angular-6 CLI does not eject webpack config. Could you provide me any solution or any approach so that I can have separate java-script files for seperate components?